# Image counter in JSP

Tags: jsp, counter

Need to do Image counter in JSP for  how many clicks have clicked for advertisement?
Front-End : JSP
Backend   : Mysql

or

Any other procedure methods for counting number of clicks in advertisement using JSP

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) and map it on an `url-pattern` covering the image's URL. Then basically do the following in `doFilter()` method:

```
clickDAO.increment(request.getRequestURI());
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

And in the `ClickDAO#increment()` just basically do an `UPDATE click SET count = count + 1 WHERE image = ?`.

At least, the JSP is the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) place to implement this logic.